# Open bootstrap dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see I created a `btn-group`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="btn-group inline">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" >Offline</a>

              <a class="btn btn-info" id="print_map_btn">Print</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="print_options">
                <li data-option="complete_map"><a href="#">Complete</a></li>
                <li data-option="map_sector"><a href="#">Act</a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you click on the Arrow on the right, the dropdown opens

I would like to achieve that when someone clicks on the `Print` button on the left, the dropdown opens.

I tried to achieve it like this:

```
var print_btn = $('#print_map_btn');

print_btn.click(function(){
    $('.btn-group').addClass('open');
});
```

But it won't work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13893/

**How can I fix it?** Thanks

Comment: You don't need the added jQuery script. Just add `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the trigger. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13895/

Comment: @ChrisYongchu great It works! Could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you're trying to do, just simply add the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute to the link or button you want to toggle the dropdown menu.

I've updated your fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13895/